# "Adicionar chave de host correta em known_hosts" / múltiplas chaves de host ssh por nome de host?

Tags: jenkins

Estou com um erro que talvez algums dos Srs, tenham enfrentado entre o Jenkins e o GIT.

A maquina do JENKINS se conecta com uma maquina do GIT, más na hora do PUSH caso ele se conecte com outra maquina (réplica) vai dar um erro!
Porém estou fazendo uma solução temporária toda x tenho que remover o arquivo know_hosts manualmente, executando um "rm -rf"

Comment: Poderia postar alguma fonte para ajudar a entender melhor?

Comment: Não daria para colocar no `.gitignore` esse arquivo ?